# How to get text on top of a partial image overlay?

Tags: html, css

I can't get this text to position (and center) itself on top of this image overlay I made.

The code of the image and its overlay is:

```css
#post {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px;
}

#post img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #fafafa;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.overlay:before {
  content: "";
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<div id="post">
  <div class="overlay">
    Hello!
    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/766845496593219594/874918388856684574/image0.png" />
  </div>
```

It keeps appearing like this:

[An image of Childe from Genshin Impact with an overlay over him, and "Hello!" at the top of the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7UaT.png)

I want the text ("Hello!") to be ON TOP of the overlay, centered and not affected by the overlay. I'd also like to be able to put at least 2 lines of text. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already created a relative parent (the `.overlay`), we can wrap the text node, which is currently naked, with a simple `span`— basically, something which lets us target and position it.

```css
#post {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px;
}

#post img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #fafafa;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.overlay:before {
  content: "";
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}

.overlay .text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  bottom: 22px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="post">
  <div class="overlay">
    <span class="text">Hello!</span>
    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/766845496593219594/874918388856684574/image0.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7efawk8q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML is

```
<div id="post">
         <div class="overlay">
         <span class="text">Hello!</span>
         <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/766845496593219594/874918388856684574/image0.png"/>
      </div>
```

CSS is

```
.overlay{
  position: relative;
}

.overlay .text{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 120px;
}
```

See Position's Approach [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0):

target your text with a `span` class and add a `top` element to that with the `.overlay` and `.overlay::before`

```css
#post {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px;
  }
  
  #post img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
    border: 2px solid #fafafa;
  }
  
  .overlay {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .overlay:before {
    content: "";
    z-index: 5;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 25%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
  }
  
  .overlay span {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    bottom: 22px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 10%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
```

```html
    <div id="post">
        <div class="overlay">
          <span>Hello!</span>
          <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/766845496593219594/874918388856684574/image0.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
```